# Python socket stops after input

Tags: sockets, python-3.x

I'm trying to execute commands over socket, but the program stops itself after one input. I'm completely new at sockets and this is what all I did.

Client:

```
import socket


HOST = input("Enter the ip: ")
PORT = 7629
addr = (HOST, PORT)
clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect((addr))

#
while True:
    msg = input("Enter command> ")
    msg = str.encode(msg)
    clientsocket.send(msg)
    receivemsg = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()
    print(receivemsg)



#
```

Server:

```
import socket
import os
import sys

host = '0.0.0.0'
port = 7629
size = 1024
addr = (host, port)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((addr))
s.listen(20)

while True:
    print("Listening.")
    client ,adress = s.accept()
    data = client.recv(size)
    print("received message: ", data.decode())
    if data.decode() == "dir":
        msg = "succesful!"
        client.send(msg.encode())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your client to this:

```
import socket

HOST = input("Enter the ip: ")
PORT = 7629
addr = (HOST, PORT)
#clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#clientsocket.connect((addr))

while True:
    msg = input("Enter command> ")
    msg = str.encode(msg)
    clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    clientsocket.connect((addr))
    clientsocket.send(msg)
    receivemsg = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()
    print(receivemsg)
    clientsocket.close()
```

Note the code in your server side. If the the sent command is 'dir' then it will send back "successful", otherwise your client will not receive any message back and it will wait forever.

Comment: Thank you so much!